# The result of this expression has type bool and is implicitly ignored when using if then else in F#

Tags: f#

The full error is stated as "**The result of this expression is implicitly ignored. Consider using 'ignore' e.g. 'expr |> ignore', or ' e.g. 'let result = expr'**"

Full disclosure -> I am totally new to F# and trying to get up to speed on how to translate where applicable my knowledge of OOP to Functional Programming. I saw 1 other post on SO for this specific error but it didn't directly relate to my scenario.

```
module WebAPI =
let DoesSpecifiedHeaderExist(content: string[], searchString: string) = 
    if (content.Length > 0) then 
        for s in content do 
            if (s.Trim() = searchString.Trim()) then true else false
    else content |> ignore
```

Code requirement isn't complicated as I simply want to iterate through a string array searching for a value provided in searchString. If I find a match I return true otherwise return false. I'm sure there are other ways to do this but I'd really like to understand the issue.

The error is happening within the loop on the if..then..else block but I don't understand why I'm getting the error or how to correct the code. How is the result of the expression implicitly ignored when I'm explicitly returning either true or false on the condition and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that a for loop returns unit.  So the type of

```
if (s.Trim() = searchString.Trim()) then true else false
```

is `bool` while the type of

```
for s in content do 
    if (s.Trim() = searchString.Trim()) then true else false
```

is `unit`.

So within the for loop you generate a true/false value and then do nothing with it, the result(s) never make it out of the loop.

For what your actually trying to do in this code you might want to look a List.tryFind. Something like this maybe:

```
let DoesSpecifiedHeaderExist(content: string[], searchString: string) = 
    match (List.tryFind (fun v -> v = searchString) content) with
    | Some s -> true
    | None -> false
```

So tryFind returns `Some` if it finds the search string; otherwise it returns `None`, the match converts the result to a Boolean.  Another possibility is

```
List.tryFind (fun v -> v = searchString) content |> Option.isSome
```

Using the Option.isSome to convert the Option to a boolean.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense when put in context of your explanation. Seems there may be bit more of a learning curve coming from C# background. The concept of having no explicit way to break and return a value along with lacking understanding of implicit unit assignments in F# will apparently be a mindset challenge for me. If you can suggest some good reading references to get a newbie migrating from OOP fairly quick I'd love to hear them. Otherwise thanks. Been scratching my head for a bit with this one.

Comment: Loops are generally substituted with functions in the List, Seq and Array modules. Your first priority should perhaps be to go through these functions. Some of the simpler and most used are map, iter, tryFind.

Comment: No point writing `if test then true else false`. It boils down to `test`.

Comment: Thanks guys. All good info so I see I've got some serious homework ahead.